# Merging countries/provinces in shapefile for plotting with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis

I am trying to plot some provincial data about Canada on a map. However, some of my data is aggregated into regions so I need to combine some provinces on my map. I am aware the provinces in my data overlap with some of the regions (Alberta is part of the Prairies), but this is what I have.

Example data I want to plot:

```
data_to_plot <- data.frame(province = c("Alberta", "Atlantic Canada", "British Columbia", 
                                        "Ontario", "Prairies", "Quebec"),
                           data = runif(6, 1E6, 1E8))
```

The shapefile for Canada with provinces can be downloaded [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=dcbcdf86939548af81efbd2d732336db).

What I tried so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rgdal)

# Import the shape file
shapefile <- readOGR("[path to shape file]", "Canada")
shapefile_df <- fortify(shapefile, region = "NAME")
shapefile_df$id[shapefile_df$id == "Yukon Territory"] <- "Yukon"

# Replace `id` with new region name, where applicable
shapefile_df <- shapefile_df %>%
  mutate(id = case_when(id %in% c("New Brunswick", "Nova Scotia", "Prince Edward Island") ~ "Atlantic Canada",
                        id %in% c("Saskatchewan", "Manitoba") ~ "Prairies",
                        TRUE ~ id))

# Merge map data with data to plot
map.data <- full_join(shapefile_df, data_to_plot, by = c("id" = "province"))

# Plot the map
ggplot(map.data) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id, fill = data),
               size = 0, alpha = 0.9) +
  geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
            color = "grey", size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5)
```

As you can see below, this creates a mess. Preferably I would also remove any borders between provinces within the same region. I admit I don't know much about shape files or GIS, so please let me know if what I want to do is impossible.

[image: example_plot]

Comment: That's what it looks like when rows get re-ordered. It's not clear where in your code that is happening (usually the `dplyr` join functions keep the row order, unlike `base::merge`), but I would advise adding a `row_id` column to your `shapefile_df`  as soon as it is created, and make sure it stays ordered and unduplicated at every subsequent step.

Comment: You might take a look at the `sf` package, which makes these sorts of operations on spatial data pretty simple and inline with tidyverse tools, including `ggplot` via the `geom_sf`

Answer (score 1):

For a dataframe made by `fortify` to work properly, the rows have to be in the original order they were in when it was made, otherwise you will get that weird effect you are seeing in North Canada.  I like to add a row id to a fortified object if I am going to be doing any merges and joins with it.  So:

```
shapefile <- readOGR("[path to shape file]", "Canada")
shapefile_df <- fortify(shapefile, region = "NAME")
shapefile_df$row_id <- 1:nrow(shapefile_df)
```

Then rename variables and do joins, etc, and before you plot it do:

```
shapfile_df <- shapefile_df %>% arrange(row_id)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not not solve my problem. It gives me the same result as before.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but for the sake of completeness... I second camille's suggestion to use `sf`. Is this what you're after?

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data_to_plot <- data.frame(
    province=c("Alberta", "Atlantic Canada", "British Columbia", "Ontario", "Prairies", "Quebec"),
    data=runif(6, 1E6, 1E8)
)
shapefile <- st_read('/temp/r/Canada/Canada.shp')
shapefile$NAME <- as.character(shapefile$NAME)
shapefile$NAME[shapefile$NAME == "Yukon Territory"] <- "Yukon"

# Replace `id` with new region name, where applicable
shapefile <- shapefile %>%
  mutate(NAME = case_when(NAME %in% c("New Brunswick", "Nova Scotia", "Prince Edward Island") ~ "Atlantic Canada",
                        NAME %in% c("Saskatchewan", "Manitoba") ~ "Prairies",
                        TRUE ~ NAME))

# Merge map data with data to plot
map.data <- full_join(shapefile, data_to_plot, by = c("NAME"="province"))

ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data=map.data, aes(fill=data))
```

[image]